# can't find variable '$' on compute engine

Tags: jquery, reactjs, google-compute-engine

I just created a trial for a google compute engine, and I finished setting up an experimental node web app that I've been working on. The app works fine on my computer, but on the compute engine, it complains about a missing `$` which is the jQuery variable.

my index.ejs file looks like this:

```
<html>
 <!-- header stuff -->
 <body>
 <!-- body stuff -->
  <script src='https://fb.me/react-0.14.5.js'></script>
  <script src='https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.5.js'></script>
  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js'></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/bundle.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

jquery is linked before bundle.js

the problem is in the bundle.js file (which is a browserify bundle used to bundle react components, one of which uses jQuery ajax `$.ajax` this is where the error is)

link to the app running on compute engine: https://8080-dot-2015515-dot-devshell.appspot.com/?authuser=0

look at the console error.

again, this works fine on my machine, not sure why its complaining on compute engine.

Comment: jquery is linked 3rd

Comment: have you tried putting your jQuery library in you head?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter i meant before bundle

Comment: @StealthSpoder i can try that

Comment: why do I have a down vote?

Comment: You don't need to put it in your `<head>`. Just put it above react.

Comment: i just tried to put it in head, above everything, still same error

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again

Comment: @stackErr nope.. same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what worked for me was to change the jQuery version from 2.x to 1.12. I don't know why this worked, if anyone knows, feel free to tell me

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the compute engine code? I had this problem elsewhere and jquery had been set into non conflict mode, see here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/
It means you may need to reference $g... Rather than just $.
If you can check the source code, you may find the correct prefix there.

Comment: Ok i'll look into it

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: No it didn't work. But I changed the jQuery version to 1.12 and the error went away. Strange